# Checked other checkbox on selecting of single checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

```
  1.    <p:column align="center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Select" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="select">
                        <p:ajax event="click" update="CoverageList,select" />
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:column> 

2.<p:column align="center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{label.coverage}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="CoverageList" style="width: 120px"
                        value="#{policy.selectedCoverageCodes}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{policy.coverageCodes}" />
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </p:column>
```

Need to select multiple checkboxs on clicking of single checkbox....

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript version

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
        elements[i].checked = !elements[i].checked;
    }
}
```

if you have jQuery use this

```
$("#CoverageList").click(function() {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        $('#actions').find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", checked_status);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....Yes you are right,this will work properly for javascript/Jquery.But we are avoiding the use of javascript/jquery.Please suggest any solution in jsf/prime faces.

Comment: Please suggest any solution in jsf/prime faces